# On iOS, what are the options of linking from the Free version to the Full version?

Tags: ios, uikit

To display the following at the bottom of the iPhone / iPad screen:
[image]

(font is grey, and has a dotted line under the words "Full version"... If the user taps on "Full version", it will take the user to the full version app on App Store -- it is ok if all 2 lines or all of the bottom line is clickable)

It seems there are a few options:

1. use 2 `UILabel`, and make it clickable at the bottom label
2. use `UITextView` -- but is it true that the link's URL must be in the text for it to be clickable, and therefore will also be shown to the user?
3. use `UIButton`... and make it clickable... but it seems no way to make the border on the second line style that way?
4. use `UIWebView` -- and in fact, the 2 desired lines shown above are styled using HTML and CSS... but will using `UIWebView` be too much of an overkill or take up too much memory?

What is a good or best practice for adding a link like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it all programmatically, you could use a `UIButton` with type `Custom`, then add some labels as subviews or do custom drawing.

Another method is to subclass a `UITextView`, and since it inherits from `UIView`, you could override the `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` method to open the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a UILabel up for the text and an empty button right on top of Full Version with backgroundColor set to clear

Comment: but what about the dotted line at the bottom?

Comment: using characters to do underline?  so if font is changed for the text and width is different, then adjust the number of dots?